# баг в firebug и надоедливый warning

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-extension

С недавнего времени начал замечать, что при открытой панели firebug'a иногда не с первого раза срабатывает клик левой или правой кнопкой мыши, независимо от сайта. С мышью все в порядке, с производительностью компьютера тоже. Если панель свернуть - баг остается, а если закрыть - пропадает. что это, и как с этим бороться?
И на закуску: кто как избавился от тучи желтеньких надоедливых предупреждений о SHA-1? Без полного отключения всех warning'ов.
Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: это может быть не баг в firebug, а какое-то другое  расширение браузера рекламу пытается запустить на странице... или еще что-то...

Comment: Если вы подозреваете баг в Firebug - почитайте их рекомендации по поиску ошибок. Если у вас проблема с браузером - спросите на тематических ресурсах, у FF большое и активное сообщество.